# Can outdegree concept be used for topo sort of directed acyclic graph

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

Just like Kahns algorithm works for indegree can we use similar approachusing outdegree
Approach :
1.removing vertex with 0 outdegree 2.removing edges attached to it
3.and repeating this ?

Comment: You mean Kahn's algorithm after reversing all the edges... yes, it works fine and produces a reverse topological sort.

Comment: Yes something like that but couldn’t find a proof somewhere that could verify it @MattTimmermans